# Send axios (api) requests from react app deployed on heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, axios

In development, when i was running the react server on localhost:3000. I used proxy in package.json to set the baseurl for my backend server, which was running on loacalhost:5000. So i just edited proxy in package.json to "localhost:5000". So all the api requests sent from axios will be directed to that url.

```
axios.get("/name").then(res=>({...}))
```

A request identical to the above would be redirected to:

```
localhost:5000/name
```

In production, when i deployed the app on online platforms like heroku and vercel. The api requests sent from react-app through axios, all failed. When deploying on heroku/vercel, I changed the proxy to the online backend url.

I want to know how to change the proxy when a react app is deployed online (preferably on heroku/vercel). So that my api requests won't fail.

Tech stack: react for frontend, axios to send requests and firebase for the backend. The backend is also deployed on heroku.

Any kind of support would be appreciated. Even if there's a better platform to deploy the app, I can switch to that as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a config object and pick `base_url` based on the env.
On local, it will pick `development` url and on Heroku it will use `production`.

```
const configs = {
  development: {
    SERVER_URI: 'localhost:5000',
  },
  production: {
    SERVER_URI: 'HEROKU_URI',
  },
};

module.exports.config = configs[process.env.NODE_ENV];
```

Also replace your axios calls like this:

```
axios.get(`${config.SERVER_URI}/name`).then(res=>({...}))
```

Comment: How will the production and development be differentiated? Will that be done automatically or do i have to specify something?

Comment: Based on your build command. It will set `NODE_ENV` and pick up configs automatically.

Comment: What about api call like this: 

axios.get("URL_FROM_ANOTHER_DOMAIN/calendar'+'?listing_id='+fantastic_id+'&start_date=2021-01-01")

How to pass this problem when deploying on vercel